# How to test an ASP page?

Tags: asp-classic

I had to code an Active X DLL which is called from an ASP page.

I am convinced (by debug tracing) that my DLL returns the correct value when its function is invoked from the ASP page, but the page does not display the result as it should.

What's the quickest/easiest way to do some debugging? Can I run ASP locally? If so, I can just add a few print()s (or equivalent), unless there is an easy to use FOSS IDE that will allow me to step through the page in a debugger.

Btw, I notice tags for ASP.Net & ASP-classic.  The web page is copyright 2002, so I would guess classic (?)

---

Update: I should have said, I only ave access the browser's "view page source", not to any files that may have been necessary to create the ASP page originally

---

Thanks for the help. Yes, control panel add/remove windows components, add IIS then copy the ASP file into c:\inetpub\wwwroot  sprinkle a few `response.write` around the ASP code & Bob's your anutie's live-in lover

Comment: ASP.NET pages will generally end in .aspx and have <%@ Page Title="XYZ" Language="C#" (or VB)
ASP classic generally end in .ASP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is classic ASP, you can try to to run it (or the part relevant to you) locally. Copy the VB code, put it into a .vbs file, make minimal changes (like using `WScript.Echo` instead of `Response.Write`).

You can also run VBScript code with minimal modifications in the VBA editor of MS Office. This way you have a chance to debug the code line-by line.

If none of this is feasible for you, sprinkle `Response.Write` în the critical sections and comment out any `On Error Resume Next` statements. This way you can try to spot the error while running the code on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response (+1).  I can't believe that the VB code will run that way (serial port access & such), but `response.write` sounds good.  Now, since I don't have an IIS server (is that what I need for ASP pages?), how best to execute the page? (I do have a local Apacahe server on my PC fo rtesting PHP pages, but that doesn't seem to help :)

Comment: @mawg: Yes, you would need an IIS Server. There is one in every Windows installation, even the desktop varieties. Install it via Add/Remove Windows Components. I wrote my answer assuming that you deal with classic ASP, which predominantly is VBScript. If serial port access happens within the ActiveX component, I don't see why it would not work within a VBS/VBA environment. If you have VB.NET code, debugging would work best in a native VB.NET IDE, like the free Visual Studio Express (web developer edition).

Comment: +1 Oic, thanks. I will try that then ... I guess that I can just refernce the page as file:// ? or does it need to be localhost? if so, where is localhost? sorry, extremely tired now, gtg bed & will get back to you tomorrow. Thanks very much for helping

Comment: @mawg: No offense, but it looks like you are seriously lacking some background in how web servers work. Based on your update (you don't have any access to the original sources) I'm not even sure if you can debug the problem at all.

Comment: no offenve taken. But if it were a PHP page I would install Apache & a PHP server locally, then call up the page in the browser.  For instance, on a windows box, I would install XAMPP and put my PHP page in c:\xampp\httdcos\my_pagr.php and then in the browser I would load http://localhost/my_page.php  Teh Apache server would take care of serving the page and the PHP server would interpret it.  Isn't this something very similar, but with IIS & ASP?  I freely admit that I know noting of IIS or ASP, but all I want to do is add a few print statements for debugging porpoises ...

Comment: @mawg: It's exactly the same thing with ASP(.NET) and IIS. You set up the web server, copy the files to the web root directory and it cares for the rest.

Comment: Thanks (+1 - and +1 for the "no offence" before :-)   I guess I'd better go google how to do that, then ...   ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if I could use  Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Comment: @mawg: Sure you could. You still need IIS though.